# PDB: How to inspect local variables of functions in nested stack frames?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

#### Context:

I'm running some python code thru PDB (Python debugger). When I set and subsequently hit a breakpoint, I can inspect the local variables using:

```
(Pdb) locals()
```

This prints out a nice dict of name, value pairs of the local variables in the current scope in which I'm paused. Perfect!

I can also see a stack trace using the PDB `where` command which results in something like this:

```
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bdb.py(400)run()
-> exec cmd in globals, locals
  <string>(1)<module>()
  .../main.py(116)<module>()
-> run()
  .../main.py(104)run()
-> res = quicksort(res)
> .../main.py(68)quicksort()
-> if len(v) <= 1:
```

In this example output, I'm paused in the `quicksort()` function which was called by the `run()` function.

So far, so good.

#### Question:

If I can inspect the `quicksort()` function's local variables with a call to `locals()`, how can I similarly inspect the local variables of the `run()` function?

In other words, how can I inspect the local variables of a function which is nested in the call stack?

**Important clarification**: I **DON'T** want to `continue` or `step` into `run()` to inspect its local variables. I want to inspect (from my current, paused perspective) the local variables in the `run()` stack frame currently nested in the call stack.

Comment: You got to get into the run() scope by pressing 's', then inspect local variables.

Comment: No, this is very important: I **don't** want to step into the `run()` function. I want to inspect the local variables of `run()` from my current paused state. I cannot step or continue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`(i)pdb` offer commands `up` and `down`, allowing you to travel via call stack, this way you can visit higher levels of your call and inspect local variables there.

You can jump up or down the call stack using `u(p)` or `d(own)`.
You can also specify a number of frames to by giving it as an argument to `u(p)` or `d(own)`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I now realize I always thought the `u` command was actually the `until` command (and thought the behavior was actually that of the `return` command). That is, I thought the `u` command continued until the return of the current function. You've made me realize I was wrong, and that `up` was what I was looking for. Thanks again!